# IONIC add android platform

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on Ionic framework.

While creating android folder by using following equation,

```
cordova platform add android
```

But it gives me following error,

```
**Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@0.0.8
```

(node:11862) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@0.0.8
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for cordova-android@0.0.8
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jayvyas/.npm/_logs/2018-07-12T11_24_03_356Z-debug.log
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform/addHelper.js:312:25
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:808:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
(node:11862) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11862) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.**

I tried lots of solutions, but no success.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

1-remove android platform directory manually
or using this command

```
    ionic cordova platform remove android
```

2-be sure to download sdk platforms you need via android studio -> Tools  -> SDK Manager

3-then try:

```
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```

or a specific version of android:

```
ionic cordova platform add android@7.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside package.json there is a line

```
"android": "0.0.8",
```

Just delete this line.

Answer (score 0):

first remove platform

> ionic cordova platform remove android

after that add platform

> ionic cordova platform add android@latest